# Argument and magnitude of complex number

Tags: complex-numbers

Find the argument and magnitude of $z=i^{i^{i}}$.

**Argument:**

I took the $\ln$ on both sides, $\ln z = i^{i}\ln i$

Using Euler's form, $i= e^{i \frac{π}{2}}$, I got $\ln z = i^{i}{i \frac{π}{2}}$.

Now on trying to simplify this i did not get any result.I also tried to solve just the powers once and then putting it in the final equation but that proved to be too complicated. How do I proceed after this ?

**Magnitude:**

It follows the same basic steps as above so no progress here too. The provided answer of the argument is:

[image]

The answer of the magnitude is not given.

Comment: Why you don't try to take $\ln$ of both sides again?

Comment: it gets too complicated. and then there is no way to simplify it.

Comment: $\ln z= i\ln i $ then $\ln z = i\times i \times \frac{pi}{2}= - \frac{\pi}{2}$ can you finish it off from here? (Also just to note, I took the principle log)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well $$i=e^{i \frac{\pi}{2}} \implies i^i=e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}}$$
$$ \implies i^{(i^i)}=i^{e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}}}=(e^{i \frac{\pi}{2}})^{e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}}}=e^{i\cdot(\frac{\pi}{2}e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}})}$$
So the magnitude is just $1$ and the arguement is $\frac{\pi}{2}e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}}$